# Loading Image from SQL Server DB Image Field into UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql-server, image, ipad

We have images stored in our SQL Server db in an image type field. Im just wanting to know how I go about getting them into a UIImageView in my iPad app. My iPad app talks to the SQL Server over an OData service provider so the image field comes across as type NSData so I tried the following code already:

```
UIImage *currentImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[currentEntityImage getEntityImageData]];
[myImageView setImage:currentImage];
```

Where "[currentEntityImage getEntityImageData]" is the NSData field converted from the image field. The problem is I can never get anything to display in the UIImageView.

Here is the corresponding code I use in our .net application that shows the image correctly:

```
Dim EntImage As EntityImage = CType(e.Entities.Item(0), EntityImage)
Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(EntImage.EntityImage)
Me.imgEntityImage.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
```

This works fine and shows the image correctly (i am accessing the same data on both platforms).

Any ideas on what im missing in my obj-c code? Ive been pulling my hair out all morning on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
NSData *imageData =[NSData dataWithData:[currentEntityImage getEntityImageData]];  
UIImage *animalImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];  
[myImageView setImage:animalImage];
```

Comment: Made no difference. Isnt the first line of code redundant because [currentEntityImage getEntityImageData] is already of type NSData

Answer (score 0):

maybe the data returned from OData is encoded Base64. 
Try decoding it with http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html

Hope it helps